# 2 fixed width sidebars with a central div that fills remaining space

Tags: css

How can I let the green `div` be `width: 100%` with the other two `div`s on the same line with fixed `width`.

My idea is to let the two side `div`'s have fixed width and the central `div` to be `width: 100%` (taking up the remainder space).

Is it possible to implement this situation?

### CSS:

```
.boxMenu {
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
}
.boxConteudoMaster {
    height:40px;
    background-color:#4cff00;
    float:left;
}
.boxNotificacao {
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<div class="boxMenu"></div>
<div class="boxConteudoMaster">asd</div>
<div class="boxNotificacao"></div>
```

[**JSFIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/leandrodavimg/665Ve/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your after something like this:

### HTML:

```
<div class="boxMenu"></div>
<div class="boxNotificacao"></div>
<div class="boxConteudoMaster">Testing...</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.boxMenu {
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
}
.boxConteudoMaster {
    height:40px;
    background-color:#4cff00;
    width: 100%;
}
.boxNotificacao {
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#000;
    float:right;
}
```

So we can float the 2 `div`s that we want fixed (`float:left` and `float: right`) and then after put are middle `div` to `width: 100%`.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/665Ve/7/)